# 5 column with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

i am working in a page and i started using bootstrapp 3, I love the grid system but i am having some problems with a 5 column page. I need something like this...

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|    |                         |    |
|    |       header space      |    |
|  1 |-------------------------|  5 |
|    |                         |    |
|    | ____ _____________ ____ |    |
|    | |  | |           | |  | |    |
|    | |2 | |     3     | | 4| |    |
|    | |  | \-----------/ |  | |    |
|    | |  | _____________ |  | |    | 
|    | |  | |           |      |    |
|    | |  | |           |      |    |
|    | |  | \-----------/      |    |
```

I had problems with the width of the page because i want the grid to be full width but i don´t found that at the bootstrap page.

I also had a problem at header space because the margin that the 1 and 2 columns had,
header space doesn´t need that space as you can see.

And also between 1 & 2 columns and 4 & 5, i need more margin than 2 & 3 & 4.

I can get to it by making a layout wuth my own css, but bootstrap it´s so clean and complete i dont want to get my dirty hands into it.

So the quiestion it´s:

Is there a way to do al that only with bootstrap 3?

PD: English it´s not my natal language, sorry for the horrible writing.

Comment: Did you want like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jlLnK)

Comment: you can follow this way : 1) divide page in 3 root columns (left - 1, middle - header+2+3+4, right-5) 2) divide middle in 2 rows (top- header, bottom 2+3+4) 3) divide bottom row to 3 cols(left-2,mid-3,right-4 ) 4) to add extra margin use extra div inside cols for adding margins

Comment: Ok understand amost everything, i thin the only problem will be the margin between header space and rows 1 & 2

Comment: you can also use extra div in header row to add bottom margin

Comment: i used following idea to manage such tasks - expect grid only as page divider, it has only geometry rules for columns, no padding, margin, border and so on. All decoration you need you can add via extra div inside grid cell - it will help to separate grid responsibilities + avoid tones of bugs in cross-browser support

Comment: I have updated the code. Check [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jlLnK)

Comment: Not working with responsive, i can hide the two edge columns and the center one wont work responsive.